# Yii Url Manager change integer parameter to equivalent string

Tags: php, codeigniter, yii

Im trying to make url parameter string to it's integer equivalent
I want user/admins to route on index.php?r=user/admin&lvl=2, user/employees on index.php?r=user/admin&lvl=3 etc but it seems that it is not possible in yii?

I made the following rule but it's not working

```
'rules' => array(
  'user/admins' => 'user/admin/<lvl:2>',
  'user/employees' => 'user/admin/<lvl:3>'
);
```

I think this how I made it on CodeIgniter:

```
$route['user/admins'] = "user/admin/lvl/2";
$route['user/employees'] = "user/admin/lvl/3";
```

but I'm not sure in yii

Comment: Do you find better solution?

Comment: still can't find better solution

Answer (score 1):

Variables are simply mapped after the action definition and separated with a slash:

```
'rules' => array(
  'user/admins' => 'user/admin/lvl/2',
  'user/employees' => 'user/admin/lvl/3'
);
```

You can now acces url user/admins which will be routed to user controller and action admin with a $_GET variable "lvl" and value 2. Note that the value then will be a string instead of an integer, but you can easily cast it.

Comment: my controller is user and action is admin and the parameter needed is $lvl, what I want is that instead of using user/admin/lvl/2 as the url, I want to use user/admins and route me to user/admin with $lvl value = 2, is that possible in yii?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. However I updated the answer.

Comment: this one work, but my problem now is that if I use Yii::app()->createUrl('user/admin', array('lvl' => 2)) the url on the anchor tag is not changing to user/admins

Comment: Then you must give `createUrl` the whole action definition: `Yii::app()->createUrl('user/admin/lvl/2');` and not use the array()

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do that with the default rules provided by CUrlManager. But it's possible by using custom rules. For more information about their implementation see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager).

In this case you should insert the following line in rules array in your config file:

```
array('class' => 'application.components.CustomRule'),
```

And you CustomRule file should look like:

```
class CustomRule extends CBaseUrlRule {

public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params, $ampersand) {
    if ($route === 'user/admin') {
        if ($params['lvl'] == 2) {
            return 'user/admin';
        } else if ($params['lvl'] == 3) {
            return 'user/employees';
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

public function parseUrl($manager, $request, $pathInfo, $rawPathInfo) {
    if ('user/admins' == $pathInfo) {
        $_GET['lvl'] = 2;

        return 'user/admin';
    } else if ('user/employees' == $pathInfo) {
        $_GET['lvl'] = 3;

        return 'user/admin';
    }

    return FALSE;
}

}
```

Comment: is this the only way? If I want to have lot of url routes with the same approach, I need to add each one of them in this custom rules –

Comment: I don't see another way at the moment if you want to use the framework conventions. The official documentation says that in the function createURL($route, $params) the $route should be route and $params should be a list of GET parameters. So the suggested solution in the another answer break the framework conventions.